# Using XSLT version 1.0, transforming one input row into 2 different output rows in text format

Tags: xslt

I am using XSLT 1.0. in bpel2.0 for SOA 11g. I have a requirement like below:

Source file data:

"2015-08-29",901148,,Fname1,Lname1,"153 MAIN STREET",,OTTAWA,ON
"2015-08-29",901145,,Fname2,Lname2,"151 MAIN STREET",,QUEBEC,QC

## XSLT 1.0

```
  <ns1:Root-Element>
   <xsl:for-each select="/imp1:Root-Element/imp1:Rec">
    <ns1:Element_1>
      <ns1:RECTYPE>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">D</xsl:text>
      </ns1:RECTYPE>
      <ns1:Client_Number>
        <xsl:value-of select="imp1:client_number"/>
      </ns1:Client_Number>
      <ns1:Last_Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="imp1:last_name"/>
      </ns1:Last_Name>
      <ns1:First_Name>
        <xsl:value-of select="imp1:first_name"/>
      </ns1:First_Name>
      <ns1:Address_Line_1>
        <xsl:value-of select="imp1:address_1"/>
      </ns1:Address_Line_1>
</ns1:Element_1>    
    </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:for-each select="/imp1:Root-Element/imp1:Rec">

<ns1:Element_2>
      <ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">E</xsl:text>
      </ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>
      <ns1:Client_Number>
        <xsl:value-of select="imp1:client_number"/>
      </ns1:Client_Number>
      <ns1:Address_Line_2>
        <xsl:value-of select="imp1:address_2"/>
      </ns1:Address_Line_2>
</ns1:Element_2>    
  </xsl:for-each>
    </ns1:Root-Element>
```

CURRENT Output:
D901148  Fname1  Lname1  153 MAIN STREET
D901145  Fname2  Lname2  151 MAIN STREET
E901148        OTTAWA
E901145        QUEBEC

But the output should be :

D901148  Fname1  Lname1  153 MAIN STREET
E901148        OTTAWA
D901145  Fname2  Lname2  151 MAIN STREET
E901145        QUEBEC

which is not getting generated.

Source XML:

```
  <Record>
  <Rec>
  <client_number>901148</client_number>
  <sin></sin>
  <last_name>Lname1</last_name>
  <first_name>Fname1</first_name>
  <address_1>153 MAIN STREET</address_1>
  <address_2>OTTAWA</address_2>
  </Rec>
  <Rec>
  <client_number>901145</client_number>
  <sin></sin>
  <last_name>Lname2</last_name>
  <first_name>Fname2</first_name>
  <address_1>151 MAIN STREET</address_1>
  <address_2>QUEBEC</address_2>
 </Rec>
 <Record>
```

Target XML:

```
    <Root-Element>
  <ns1:Element_1>
  <ns1:RECTYPE>D</ns1:RECTYPE>
  <ns1:Client_Number>901148</ns1:Client_Number>
  <ns1:First_Name>Fname1</ns1:First_Name>
  <ns1:Last_Name>Lname1</ns1:Last_Name>
  <ns1:Address_Line_1>153 MAIN STREET</ns1:Address_Line_1>      
  </ns1:Element_1>
  <ns1:Element_1>
  <ns1:RECTYPE>D</ns1:RECTYPE>
  <ns1:Client_Number>901145</ns1:Client_Number>
  <ns1:First_Name>Fname2</ns1:First_Name>
  <ns1:Last_Name>Lname2</ns1:Last_Name>
  <ns1:Address_Line_1>151 MAIN STREET</ns1:Address_Line_1>      
  </ns1:Element_1>
  <ns1:Element_2>
  <ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>E</ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>
  <ns1:Client_Number>901148</ns1:Client_Number>   
  <ns1:Address_Line_2>OTTAWA</ns1:Address_Line_2>
  </ns1:Element_2>
  <ns1:Element_2>
  <ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>E</ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>
  <ns1:Client_Number>901145</ns1:Client_Number>   
  <ns1:Address_Line_2>QUEBEC</ns1:Address_Line_2>
  </ns1:Element_2>
  <Root-Element>
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience ...I have updated the  question. Please have a look.

Comment: Please post you input and output **as XML**.

Comment: I have posted the source and target xml

Answer (score 0):

Your code still has a lot of missing parts. Try something like the following:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Record">
    <Root-Element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Rec"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Rec" mode="elem2"/>
    </Root-Element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rec">
    <ns1:Element_1>
        <ns1:RECTYPE>D</ns1:RECTYPE>
        <ns1:Client_Number>
            <xsl:value-of select="client_number"/>
        </ns1:Client_Number>
        <ns1:First_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="first_name"/>
        </ns1:First_Name>
        <ns1:Last_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="last_name"/>
        </ns1:Last_Name>
        <ns1:Address_Line_1>
            <xsl:value-of select="address_1"/>
        </ns1:Address_Line_1>
    </ns1:Element_1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rec" mode="elem2">
    <ns1:Element_2>
        <ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>F</ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>
        <ns1:Client_Number>
            <xsl:value-of select="client_number"/>
        </ns1:Client_Number>
        <ns1:Address_Line_2>
            <xsl:value-of select="address_2"/>
        </ns1:Address_Line_2>
    </ns1:Element_2>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the folowing **well-formed input**:

```
<Record>
  <Rec>
    <client_number>901148</client_number>
    <sin/>
    <last_name>Lname1</last_name>
    <first_name>Fname1</first_name>
    <address_1>153 MAIN STREET</address_1>
    <address_2>OTTAWA</address_2>
  </Rec>
  <Rec>
    <client_number>901145</client_number>
    <sin/>
    <last_name>Lname2</last_name>
    <first_name>Fname2</first_name>
    <address_1>151 MAIN STREET</address_1>
    <address_2>QUEBEC</address_2>
  </Rec>
</Record>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root-Element xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1">
   <ns1:Element_1>
      <ns1:RECTYPE>D</ns1:RECTYPE>
      <ns1:Client_Number>901148</ns1:Client_Number>
      <ns1:First_Name>Fname1</ns1:First_Name>
      <ns1:Last_Name>Lname1</ns1:Last_Name>
      <ns1:Address_Line_1>153 MAIN STREET</ns1:Address_Line_1>
   </ns1:Element_1>
   <ns1:Element_1>
      <ns1:RECTYPE>D</ns1:RECTYPE>
      <ns1:Client_Number>901145</ns1:Client_Number>
      <ns1:First_Name>Fname2</ns1:First_Name>
      <ns1:Last_Name>Lname2</ns1:Last_Name>
      <ns1:Address_Line_1>151 MAIN STREET</ns1:Address_Line_1>
   </ns1:Element_1>
   <ns1:Element_2>
      <ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>F</ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>
      <ns1:Client_Number>901148</ns1:Client_Number>
      <ns1:Address_Line_2>OTTAWA</ns1:Address_Line_2>
   </ns1:Element_2>
   <ns1:Element_2>
      <ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>F</ns1:Rec_Type_TFSA>
      <ns1:Client_Number>901145</ns1:Client_Number>
      <ns1:Address_Line_2>QUEBEC</ns1:Address_Line_2>
   </ns1:Element_2>
</Root-Element>
```

Note that the namespace associated with the `ns1:` prefix is something I made up, since you did not provide it.

Comment: @ michael.hor257k     please check the required output. This is not what I want.

Comment: @BapuAbhi Please be more specific!

Comment: @BapuAbhi Why is this question not answered?